# Redirect only working on some controller actions

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

A redirect, called by the private function `r()`, in the `edit` function works, but not in the `delete`.

Even commenting out the `allowMethod` doesn't help.

Any ideas why that would be?

```
/**
    * Edit method
    *
    * @param string|null $id Task id.
    * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
    * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
    */
public function edit($id = null)
{
    //get task
    $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
    ]);

    $this->r();
    ...
}

/**
    * Delete method
    *
    * @param string|null $id Task id.
    * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects to index.
    * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
    */
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    //get task
    $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
    ]);

    $this->r();
    ...
}

private function r()
{
    $this->Flash->error(__('Not enough permissions to edit this task.')); 
    return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'tasks', 'action' => 'view',687]);
}
```

I modified the `Controller` class in `/vendor` to output the `$response` object.

Debug of headers following `edit` redirect:

```
CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php (line 695)
object(Cake\Http\Response) id:0 {
'status' => (int) 302
'contentType' => 'text/html'
'headers' => [
'Content-Type' => [
(int) 0 => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
],
'Location' => [
(int) 0 => 'http://localhost:9000/spt/tasks/view/687',
],
]
'file' => null
'fileRange' => [ ]
'cookies' => object(Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieCollection) id:1 {
protected cookies => [ ]
}
'cacheDirectives' => [ ]
'body' => ''
}
```

Debug of headers following `delete` redirect:

```
CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php (line 695)
object(Cake\Http\Response) id:0 {
'status' => (int) 302
'contentType' => 'text/html'
'headers' => [
'Content-Type' => [
(int) 0 => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
],
'Location' => [
(int) 0 => 'http://localhost:9000/spt/tasks/view/687',
],
]
'file' => null
'fileRange' => [ ]
'cookies' => object(Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieCollection) id:1 {
protected cookies => [ ]
}
'cacheDirectives' => [ ]
'body' => ''
}
```

**Edit #1**

Prior to this post, $this->r(), had logic to determine if it needed to redirect or not:

```
//code evaluating the need to redirect

//redirect if not editable by user
if($isEditable === false)
{
    $this->Flash->error(__('Not enough permissions to edit this task.')); 
    return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'tasks', 'action' => 'view',$task->id]);
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

**Edit #2**

This seems to work and offer some reusability:

```
   /**
    * Edit method
    *
    * @param string|null $id Task id.
    * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
    * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
    */
public function edit($id = null)
{
    //get task
    $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
    ]);

    if($this->r() === false)
    {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Not enough permissions to edit this task.')); 
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'tasks', 'action' => 'view',687]);
    }
    
    //rest of controller:action code
}

/**
    * Delete method
    *
    * @param string|null $id Task id.
    * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects to index.
    * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
    */
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    //get task
    $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
    ]);

    if($this->r() === false)
    {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Not enough permissions to edit this task.')); 
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'tasks', 'action' => 'view',687]);
    }
    
    //rest of controller:action code
}

private function r()
{
    //logic to determine $isEditable
    return $isEditable
}
```

Returning null, stops the processing of the action, the view no longer gets the variables passed and fails.

Assuming that I now have to move the conditional check in the controller instead of the `$this->r()` and redirect accordingly.

Comment: Those headers look identical to me. What does the delete function do instead of redirecting?

Comment: Shouldn't both functions have `return $this->r();` instead of just `$this->r();`?

Comment: @gregschmidt it just deletes a row before it has its own redirect. I think the baked delete link does a post, but that shouldn't change anything? The edit does nothing of that nature. `$this->r()` has the return part, and should make it so that both edit and delete don't continue and redirect. The idea is fetch the record, run `$this->r()` and redirect aborting the rest of the function.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how return values work. `$this->r()` returns something to your controller function, but that controller function needs to return the result it gets in order to stop running and make the redirect actually happen. Try `return $this->r();` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, I'm misunderstanding how this works. See edit #1. Long story short, I think I need to be evaluating the need to redirect in the controller and not in `$this->r()`. I was trying to have something reusable in both edit and delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's working now. Essentially, function returns boolean that is used to redirect.

```
 /**
    * Edit method
    *
    * @param string|null $id Task id.
    * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
    * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
    */
public function edit($id = null)
{
    //get task
    $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
    ]);

    if($this->r() === false)
    {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Not enough permissions to edit this task.')); 
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'tasks', 'action' => 'view',687]);
    }
    
    //rest of controller:action code
}

/**
    * Delete method
    *
    * @param string|null $id Task id.
    * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null Redirects to index.
    * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
    */
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    //get task
    $task = $this->Tasks->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users'],
    ]);

    if($this->r() === false)
    {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Not enough permissions to edit this task.')); 
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'tasks', 'action' => 'view',687]);
    }
    
    //rest of controller:action code
}

private function r()
{
    //logic to determine $isEditable
    return $isEditable
}
```